# Finding words strictly starting with $, Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex, cpu-word, word-boundary

I need to find all matches of word which strictly begins with "$" and contains only digits. So I wrote

```
[$]\d+
```

which gave me 4 matches for

```
$10 $10 $20a a$20
```

so I thought of using word boundaries using \b:

```
[$]\d+\b
```

But it again matched

a$20 for me.

I tried

```
\b[$]\d+\b
```

but I failed.

I'm looking for saying, ACCEPT ONLY IF THE WORD STARTS WITH $ and is followed by DIGITS. How do I tell IT STARTS WITH $, because I think \b is making it assume word boundaries which means surrounded inside alphanumeric characters.

What is the solution?

Comment: Why is this question community wiki?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the best solution but this should work. (It does with your test case)

```
(?<=\s+|^)\$\d+\b
```

Comment: This seems promising, can you tell how have you used this backreference?

Comment: (?<=) is a Positive Backreference. It assert that the characters before the dollar match the regex between the parenthesis (here the beginning of the string or one or more space)

Comment: Thanks. Can i have your gtalk id, i had some more queries.

Comment: That's not a backreference, it's a positive lookbehind.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

> \B\$\d+\b

Comment: This one works in my testing too; in your test string it finds the first two but ignores the second two.

Comment: This worked well. But it failed if i test it for #$20, it matches it as well.

Comment: Then I think you're going to have to use madgnome's regex.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, you just need to escape the $:

```
\B\$\d+\b
```

See the example matches here: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=79d0ac3b-dd2c-4872-abb4-6a9780c91fc1

Answer (score 1):

Try with ^\$\d+

where ^ denoted the beginning of a string.